# finding the average of numbers whch comes after a string in a read file with white spaces in between in python eg:Tom Bombadil_______6.5 5.5 4.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def avg(input):
    with open(input, "r") as file:
        average = []
        add = 0.0
        for line in file:
            f = line.split("_______________")
            for i in range(1, len(f)):
                add = 0.0
                l = f[i].split(" ")
                for num in l:
                    add = add + float(num)
                print(f[0], "has average", round((add / 3),1))
    return " "

f = open('input.txt', 'r')
for line in iter(f):
    print(line)


file = "input.txt"
avg(file)
```

(////input.txt/////contains these////)

```
Tom Bombadil_______6.5 5.5 4.5
Dain Kaput_______6.7 7.2 7.7
Chris Cohen_______6.8 7.8 7.3
Dirk Dirksen_______ 1.0 5.0 7.7
```

Comment: Are there always 3 numbers for each name?

Comment: yes  they are three floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with `maxsplit=` parameter. For computing the average, use [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean).

```
from statistics import mean

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        if not line.strip():    # skip blank lines
            continue
        line = line.replace('_', ' ').rsplit(maxsplit=3)
        print('{} has average {:.1f}'.format(line[0], mean(float(v) for v in line[1:])))
```

Prints:

```
Tom Bombadil has average 5.5
Dain Kaput has average 7.2
Chris Cohen has average 7.3
Dirk Dirksen has average 4.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help

```
import numpy as np
n = "Tom Bombadil_______6.5 5.5 4.5".split('_______')[1].split()
np.mean([float(x) for x in n])
```

Output

```
5.5
```